# Combine DBGrid column values

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, dbgrid

I have a DBGrid component of BDS 2006 in my application. The snapshot of the grid is as follows.

[image]

The DBGrid component is connected to a MySQL database, which gets populated at run time. The query I have used is:

```
dm.MyQpayment.SQL.Clear;
dm.MyQpayment.SQL.Add('select sdate,stime,pcid,billno,c.customer_name,s.customerid,s.total,s.amount_paid,s.balance');
dm.MyQpayment.SQL.Add(',s.payment_type,s.payment_status,s.delivery from sales_order s left join customer_details c on s.customerid=c.customerid where s.payment_status=''complete'' and s.sdate>="'+startdate+'" and s.sdate<="'+enddate+'" ');
dm.MyQpayment.Active :=true;
```

I want to dispaly `BILL NO` and `Machine id` as `BILL NO` and the values should be 2_1, if `Machine id` is 2 and `BILL NO` is 1.
Any idea how to do that?

**EDIT1**

```
select CAST(pcid AS CHAR) + "_" + CAST(billno AS CHAR) AS MachineAndBillNo
FROM tt.payment_details ;
```

this query gives me result as follows

[image]

where it gives machineandbillno=billno+pcid

Comment: It would be extremely helpful when asking questions about your data if you provided the data types of the columns. Nowhere above before your edit do you mention anything about one of the columns being `double`. What are the data types of the `pcid` and `billno` columns?

Comment: pcid and billno datatype is INTEGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the specific MySQL syntax requirements, but you have to concatenate those two fields together:

```
SELECT 
  sdate, 
  stime, 
  CONCAT(CAST(pcid AS CHAR), '_', CAST(billno AS CHAR)) AS MachineAndBillNo,
  c.customer_name,
  ...
```